# Same column name used in where clause in codeigniter

Tags: sql, arrays, codeigniter

i want to sql query like this

```
SELECT * FROM `tblName`
where `id`='007' and 
`doj` != '2014-07-26' and 
`doj` != '2014-08-04'
```

i want same column 'doj' used in where clause.

please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$dates = array(
     '2014-07-26',
     '2014-08-04'
);
$this->db->from('tblName');
$this->db->where('id','007');

// first variant
foreach($dates as $date){
$this->db->where('doj !=',$date);
}

// or second variant
$this->db->where_not_in('doj',$dates); // <- seems to be better

// finally get result
$result = $this->db->get();

if($result->num_rows()){
     var_dump($result->result_array());
} else {
     echo 'no rows found';
}
// check query
echo $this->db->last_query();

?>
```

Comment: thanks @George but i want this query dynamically or with the help of model, because `doj` will be increased after some time.

Comment: @VaibhavSinghal updated my answer, please, check it.